# what is the probabilty of 2 blank 6 sided dice

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, dice

A person has two blank 6-sided dice. They have 2 of every number (1 – 6) available to randomly distribute on the faces of the dice. Considering all possible combinations, what is the probability of rolling a seven?

Comment: What are your thoughts on the question?

Comment: Hint: What are the odds of you choose the numbers after you roll the dice?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I *knew* there was an easy way!

Comment: hint permutations and combinations.

Answer (score 3):

There are twelve digits to be randomly distributed.   Every one of them has two sevens-complements.

Imagine rolling the dice and *somehow* without looking at the digits showing, point to one of them.

Now ask: What it the probability that the other digit showing is one of its two sevens-complements?